# Como limpar elementos de uma linha da <table> ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: javascript, html

##### Preciso criar uma função que ao usuário clicar no botão "Limpar", todos os campos `input` de cada linha da `table` sejam limpos.

Consegui realizar estas funções, porém, tive que criar uma função para cada botão de cada linha!

```js
function removeLinha1() {
   document.getElementById("soma1").value = "";
   document.getElementById("soma2").value = "";
   document.getElementById("resultado1").value = "";
}

function removeLinha2() {
   document.getElementById("subt1").value = "";
   document.getElementById("subt2").value = "";
   document.getElementById("resultado2").value = "";
}

function removeLinha3() {
   document.getElementById("mult1").value = "";
   document.getElementById("mult2").value = "";
   document.getElementById("resultado3").value = "";
}

function removeLinha4() {
   document.getElementById("divi1").value = "";
   document.getElementById("divi2").value = "";
   document.getElementById("resultado4").value = "";
}
```

```html
<table class="class-table">
   <tr>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="soma1" /> </td>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="soma2" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="somar()">+</button> </td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado1" readonly="true" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-buttonClear" onclick="removeLinha1()">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="subt1" /> </td>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="subt2" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="subtrair()">-</button> </td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado2" readonly="true" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-buttonClear" onclick="removeLinha2()">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="mult1" /> </td>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="mult2" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="multiplicar()">*</button> </td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado3" readonly="true" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-buttonClear" onclick="removeLinha3()">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="divi1" /> </td>
      <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="divi2" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="dividir()">/</button> </td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado4" readonly="true" /> </td>
      <td> <button class="class-buttonClear" onclick="removeLinha4()">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Como posso fazer para que exista uma **ÚNICA** função para limpar esses valores?

Answer (score 2):

Aprenda a usar [escutadores de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (*event listeners*) em vez de atributos `onclick`. Então você usa a classe que existe em cada botão das linhas — no seu caso, se a classe `class-buttonClear` for apenas para esse propósito, ou então adicionar uma outra classe específica pra isso.

Use `document.querySelectorAll(".class-buttonClear")` para selecionar todos os botões pela classe, em seguida percorra todos eles com `forEach` adicionando em cada um `eventListener` com o *type* `click` e o retorno será uma função que irá selecionar a linha `tr` onde está o botão clicado que irá selecionar todos os elementos `input` fazendo outro `forEach` (percorrendo um por um) alterando o `value` para vazio:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".class-buttonClear").forEach(function(el){
   el.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(el){
         el.value = '';
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<table class="class-table">
   <tr>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="soma1"/> </td>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="soma2"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="somar()">+</button> </td>
       <td>=</td>
       <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado1" readonly="true"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-buttonClear">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="subt1"/> </td>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="subt2"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="subtrair()">-</button> </td>
       <td>=</td>
       <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado2" readonly="true"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-buttonClear">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="mult1"/> </td>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="mult2"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="multiplicar()">*</button> </td>
       <td>=</td>
       <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado3" readonly="true"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-buttonClear">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="divi1"/> </td>
       <td> <input size="3" type="text" id="divi2"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-button" onclick="dividir()">/</button> </td>
       <td>=</td>
       <td> <input type="text" size="10" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado4" readonly="true"/> </td>
       <td> <button class="class-buttonClear">Limpar</button></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Usando o mesmo princípio, você consegue fazer o mesmo para os botões das operações matemáticas sem ter que criar uma função pra cada coisa e vários `id`'s diferentes pra cada elemento (`soma1`, `soma2`, etc.).